# Is there a generic java class i can use to consume facebook api responses?

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api, jersey, jersey-client

I don't want to painfully create a class that has fields like id, name, etc. Is there a generic java class I could use instead to consume the response? I. e. extract it as key-value pairs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, java dosen't have a  class for facebook, but u can parse the response to a JSONObject class, and then u can read it very easy with key-value.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to JSONObject - it is exactly what I needed!